# Why can I not get a reference to an element I can see in AngularJS Videogular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom, videogular

I am working on getting the videogular-subtitle-plugin to work with the latest version of Videogular/AngularJS. I am new to AngularJS so I am assuming there is something stupid simple that I am just not understanding.

I am running into an issue in a directive:

```
angular.module("videogular.texttrack", [])
        .directive("vgText", [function() {

    controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {

       $scope.changeCaption = function(track) {
          var tag = $scope.trackTag[0];

          // I can get the track tag here.

          console.log( "mediaElement is", $scope.mediaElement );

          $scope.trackTag = angular.element($scope.mediaElement).find("track");

          console.log( "trackTag is", $scope.trackTag );

          ......

       link: function(scope, elem, attr, API) {


         // why can't I reference the track tag here?

         scope.trackTag = angular.element(API.mediaElement).find("track");

         console.log( "mediaElement is", API.mediaElement );

         // trackTag is empty here. I do not understand why.

         console.log( "trackTag is", scope.trackTag );

         scope.mediaElement = API.mediaElement

         ......
```

The relevant markup is:

```
<videogular vg-theme="config.theme"
    vg-player-ready="onPlayerReady($API)">
   <vg-media vg-src="config.sources"
        vg-tracks="config.tracks">
   </vg-media>
   .....
   <vg-text vg-text-src="config.plugins.subtitle"></vg-text>
```

Videogular generates the video and track tags under vg-media.

changeCaption() is called from the UI when the user change the closed captioning setting.

I am unable to reference the track tag from the link: function. However, I am able to see the element from console.log output at that point in the code, which is confusing me.

I have recreated the problem here. Open the javascript console and load:

http://miles-by-motorcycle.com/static/videogular-subtitle-plugin/app/#/

See http://miles-by-motorcycle.com/static/videogular-subtitle-plugin/text-track.js

I do not understand why I can't reference the track element in the link function but I can in the controller. I can see it listed in childNodes from the console. I've reproduced this in Chrome and Firefox under Linux.

Obviously, fixing it means simply doing the lookup in the controller but I would like to understand what I am missing here. Is it possibly because it's in some incomplete state? Or is the console lying to me and the track tag does not exist at that point in the execution?

Comment: Questions should be self contained. Please post relevant code in the question itself. Changes to repo will make this question worthless in the future. Code in that directive needs html structure shown also. If ng-repeat is invloved...look at using `$last` property of child scopes might help

Comment: Thanks. I've attempted to improve the question.

Comment: No idea what selector `API.mediaElement` points to and no `track` tags shown anywhere...in other words still not enough shown for anyone to figure a problem out

Comment: What are you trying to do? I mean specifically, what do you want to accomplish that you're trying to access this element?

Comment: I want to set the track.mode to "showing" so that closed captions display. I can do this in the "controller:" section with ease so I've solved my problem but my question has to do with why the tags created by vg-media (namely the video and track tags) can't be selected from the link: function but I can see clearly from the console.log that those tags do exist at that point in the execution.

I will try to come up with a smaller test case so I can improve the question. Basically I just want to understand why I can't select some tags in the DOM. I've never seen that behavior before.

Comment: It's just a race conditions situation.  The controller (`API`) isn't loaded yet.  I'll do a demo.  Give me a minute.

Comment: Here's a quick [demo](http://codepen.io/jme11/pen/QbZPWP?editors=101).  This is just one of the videogular demos adapted as an example.  Note that I added two log statements into the custom directive link function.  The first tries to log the mediaElement property of the API object immediately when the link is run.  The second is wrapped in a $timeout and will wait 5 seconds before it logs the same property.  Go to the demo, open the console and check the results.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense but what's confusing me was in my particular test console.log() shows mediaElement present and the track object below it but it could not be selected until later.

Comment: Of course, and if you had been selecting the element by means of DOM traversal ONLY, you'd be able to access it right away.  But, in this case, you're not using DOM traversal exclusively.  You're saying "get me the element that's referenced in this object, then find the tag track within it."  If you used something like: `trackTag = document.querySelector('track');` (or something similar via jQLite or jQuery), you'd be able to access the tag element immediately.

Comment: I want to add that I upvoted the answer below because it would probably be the approach I'd take, assuming that you need access to the compiled element and it's associated controller object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can watch for API.isReady property:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, API) {
    console.log(API.mediaElement);

    scope.onClickReplay = function() {
        API.play();
    };

    scope.onPlayerReady = function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
            console.log("onPlayerReady", API.mediaElement);
        }
    };

    scope.$watch(
        function() {
            return API.isReady;
        },
        scope.onPlayerReady.bind(scope)
    );
}
```

Codepen with demo: http://codepen.io/2fdevs/pen/bdmJyd?editors=001

Comment: This makes sense but what is confusing me is that in my test (in the link) if you open the console you can clearly see the mediaElement tag with ChildNodes containing the track tag but if you then try to reference it it comes up empty. It seems to me if the browser console is showing the tag it  should be selectable or is this a side effect of the race condition?

Comment: What you see in the console is evaluated when you open the nodes, so yes, it is also affected by the race condition.

Comment: Ah. Ok. That is the answer I was looking for. I did not know that what was displayed was not representative of the state of the object /at that time/. Ok. It all makes sense now. Thank you!